# GNU screen status bar - how to make it display shell session names?

Tags: ubuntu, gnu-screen

Let's say I have several shell "tabs" (or screens? sessions?) named bash1, bash2, etc. open in GNU screen. I want the status bar (i.e., the caption line) to display the names as "bash1 | bash2 | ..", with the currently open tab and the last open tab clearly marked.

How do I make this happen with my `.screenrc`?

Comment: I don't see anything in the screen manpage (at least for 4.00.02) that enumerates the previous window.  Current window sure (%t)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Edit or create (if not present) `/etc/screenrc` or (`~/.screenrc`) and add below code

```
autodetach on 
startup_message off 
hardstatus alwayslastline 
shelltitle 'bash'

hardstatus string '%{gk}[%{wk}%?%-Lw%?%{=b kR}(%{W}%n*%f %t%?(%u)%?%{=b kR})%{= w}%?%+Lw%?%? %{g}][%{d}%l%{g}][ %{= w}%Y/%m/%d %0C:%s%a%{g} ]%{W}'
```

`shelltitle 'bash'` can be changed once the screen is created. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>)
session name can be changed to `SESSSIONNAME` with `:sessionname SESSIONNAME`.

Comment: Yup, that does it. Need to customize it a little though - I don't want to see time, etc. Will figure that out later. Thanks!

Comment: @ARV , yeah it can be customized by user.

Comment: This, without time etc: `'%{wk}%?%-Lw%?%{=b kR}(%{W}%n*%f %t%?(%u)%?%{=b kR})%{= w}%?%+Lw%?%? %{g}]'`

Answer (score 1):

The "tab" you are referring is `Window` (correct me if I'm wrong). You should try [Byobu](https://www.byobu.org), which is a wrapper around `screen` and `tmux`.

I'm sure it comes with caption line, highlighting current window by default, but I don't remember there's ability to mark the last open window.

BUT seriously you should try `tmux`.